# Use of the Phrase 'Home Tuition'

Tags: word-usage, british-english

How to correctly use the phrase 'home tuition'? Please give some examples from both a student's and a tutor's points of view.

Are the following sentences correct:
I give/offer/provide home tuition for English to students of classes up to 12th.
(I want to say I am a home tutor.)

Comment: Your intent is not clear. *Tuition* is what you pay for education, so are you asking about what you pay for home teaching/tutoring? If you could add some rough phrases it would really help.

Comment: @user3196 - _Tuition_ also means the tutoring not just the fee for it, in fact in the UK I'd say you rarely hear _tuition_ on it's own to mean the fee for tutoring, the fees are normally called _tuition fees : the fee for tuition provided_.

Comment: @Frank I didn't know that. There seems to be a difference in usage between British English and American English (me). See [***tuition***](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/tuition) and [***tuition***](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/tuition).

Comment: @user3169 Good links - very clearly showing the difference in UK/US 'commonness'. I'd say that Kaptan Singh is looking at the most common UK definition then rather than the most common US definition.

Comment: Your clearest statement is your parenthetical statement. If you want to say you are a home tutor, say, "I am a home tutor."

Comment: @J.R. I am a home tutor. I teach spoken English. How to make a single sentence out of these two?

Comment: "I am a home tutor who teaches spoken English."

Comment: @J.R. who teach / who teaches?

Answer (score 3):

*Tuition* technically can refer to the act of teaching a private student, but in my experience (American English) this meaning is far less common than that of a fee paid for education.  If you write "I provide home tuition", you are likely to be misunderstood as offering some sort of service for helping people pay for college.  *Tutoring* is by far the more common term for the act of teaching: saying "I provide home tutoring" will be much more clear to most readers.